# How to insert a panel and hyperLint into BulletedList dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, bulletedlist

I need to generate following HTML dynamically (a BulletedList, two Panels and a HyperLink) using asp.net C# Web.UI.WebControls

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="xxx"><a href="xxx">Home</a></div>
        <div class="xxx">
            <div style="width:500px; height:200px;">
              THis is a test
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I try to use BulletedList but I can't insert Panels and a HyperList into ItemList. The requirement is to use asp.net Web Controls (Not HTML directly) and generate above HTML dynamically with UI Web Controls.

Dose anyone know how to do it with ASP.net UI.WebControls?

Comment: Just wondering why must use asp.net webcontrol ? They are still html

Comment: Why not try using Repeater instead~

Answer (score 0):

Well if you insist to use asp tag to do this you must use repeater...

As per the following code below

.aspx

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rp" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlFirst" runat="server" CssClass="xxx">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSecond" runat="server" CssClass="xxx">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubSecond" runat="server" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;">
                        This is <%# Eval("Name") %>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:Panel>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        string[] name = { "google", "yahoo" };
        string[] url = { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com" };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Url");

        // Add to DataTable
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(name[i], url[i]);

        // Check
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rp.DataSource = dt;
            rp.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```